# Как из фрагмента запустить сервис

Tags: android

Есть метод для запуска сервиса

```
public void startPlayerService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_STREAM, songFile);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_TITLE, songTitle);
    serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    isPlay = true;
    if(exo_play.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        exo_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        exo_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

Если из Activity его запускать то все работает, а если из фрагмента, то в строк startService(serviceIntent); ошибку выдает компиляции. Подскажите пожалуйста как из фрагмента запустить сервис?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените `startService` на `getActivity().startService`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Т.е. если каких-то методов у фрагмента не хватает типа startService можно через getActivity() вызвать метод активности, в котором лежит этот фрагмент и не будет ошибки?

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна да, чтобы вызывать методы активити, достаточно получить его экземпляр через getActivity()

Comment: Поняла, спасибо.